# android UDP connection, not receiving any data

Tags: android, sockets, connection, udp, packet

Im a newbie in this so please escuse me if i ask dumb questions.

Im trying to make a UDP connection between Eclipse's PC Emulator & a android phone
(or between two android phone devices).

I have a **router** and the phone connects to the internet thru router's wifi network. The PC is on same network also (direct cable router-PC connection). Im trying to send some text data from Server thread to Client thread but nothing is received/sent. :(

The **Server** java class (**RE-EDITED, Server receives msg. from Client**):

```
public class server implements Runnable 
{
    // the Server's Port
    public static final int SERVERPORT  = 6000;

    // running Server thread.
    public void run() 
    {
        Log.d("redwing","server thread started.");
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = null;

        try
        {
            // Open Server Port
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(server.SERVERPORT);
            byte[] receiveData  = new byte[32];
            byte[] sendData     = new byte[32];
            // loop until "server_finished"  becomes False.
            while(createserver.server_finished)
            {
                if(renderer.gGL!=null)  // ignore me, just a null pointer checker
                {
                    // waiting for the incoming client's message packet
                    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                    renderer.recv = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                    Log.d("server","packet received from client, ETA " + timing.getNow() + " " + renderer.recv); // timing getNow - just returns current system minute & second.

                    // server is replying to the client back with a message.
                    InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                    int port = receivePacket.getPort();

                    sendData = new String("server msg").getBytes();
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                    serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
                    renderer.sent = new String(sendData, 0, sendData.length);
                    Log.d("server","packet sent to client, ETA " + timing.getNow() + " " + renderer.sent);     // timing getNow - just returns current system minute & second.
                }
            }
            // close the socket
            if(serverSocket!=null) serverSocket.close();
            serverSocket = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("server", "Error", e);
            if(serverSocket!=null) serverSocket.close();
            serverSocket = null;
        }
        finally 
        {
            if(serverSocket!=null) serverSocket.close();
            serverSocket = null;
        }
        Log.d("redwing","server thread terminated.");
    }
}
```

and the **Client** java class (**RE-EDITED, Client does not receive msg from Server**) :

```
public class client implements Runnable 
{
    public static final int CLIENTPORT  = 5000;
    // running Client thread.
    public void run() 
    {
        Log.d("redwing","client thread started.");
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = null;

        try
        {
            // getting local address 
            clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(server.SERVERPORT);
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.100");  

            // displaying IP & hostname.
            Log.d("client", "IP: " + IPAddress.getHostAddress() + " Name: " + IPAddress.getHostName());
            byte[] sendData     = new byte[32];
            byte[] receiveData  = new byte[32];
            // Loop until client_finished becomes False.
            while(createclient.client_finished)
            {
                if(renderer.gGL!=null)  // ignore me, just a null pointer checker
                {
                    // sending a message to the server
                    sendData = timing.getNow().getBytes();
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, client.CLIENTPORT);
                    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                    renderer.sent = new String(sendData,0,sendData.length);;
                    Log.d("client","packet sent to server, ETA " + timing.getNow());  

                    // waiting for the server packet message.
                    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                    clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                    renderer.recv = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                    Log.d("client","packet received from server, ETA " + timing.getNow());
                }
            }
            // close the socket
            if(clientSocket!=null) clientSocket.close();
            clientSocket = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("client", "Error", e);
            if(clientSocket!=null) clientSocket.close();
            clientSocket = null;
        }
        finally 
        {
            if(clientSocket!=null) clientSocket.close();
            clientSocket = null;
        } 
        Log.d("redwing","client thread terminated.");
    }
}
```

the Permisions are enabled in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I'm running the Server on the android PC Emulator, and the Client on my android Phone.

Both Client & Server threads run just fine but ... the problem is that i dont get any data exchanged between them. The **client doesn't receive anyting and the server doesnt receive anything**. The packets are sent but nothing received .

What im doing wrong ?

Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After running your emulator, type it in command prompt - "telnet localhost ", then type "redir add udp:5000:6000". Connect client with port number 5000 and open udp server with port number 6000. Then you can receive client message from udp server.

[Take a look for details](http://www.coderanch.com/t/434412/Android/Mobile/Android-Emulator-as-server-Socket)

```
clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("<pc ip>"); // instead of "localhost"


public static final String SERVERIP = "127.0.0.1"; // 'Within' the emulator!  
public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;   

/* Retrieve the ServerName */  
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);  
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT, serverAddr);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.  loaded the Emulator, then i bring the Command Prompt and writing " telnet localhost " but a error appears to console that says: " Connecting to localhost ... Could not open connection to the host on port 23: Connect failed "

Comment: sorry, the telnet service not running. not i've activated telnet from control panel, services , but now it asks me for a login and a pass . what is this for ?

Comment: Sorry my bad - type it in command prompt - "telnet localhost <emulator port say 5554>" and then follow the above instruction.

Comment: All good. Added emulator port 5554.     Changed this for Server side:   serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(6000), is it right?     But to connect client with port number 5000 i should change Client side linke this:   clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(5000);  ??

Comment: Yes, go ahead, serverPort should be 6000 and client port should be 5000. That means send message from client to server port 5000 and receive message in server from 6000.

Comment: Thank you for your help until now! I've done all the changes  we've talked already in my post above, but it seems that Server receives "server msg" and it should be "client msg"! The Client receives nothing! :(  Please help. Maybe i've messed up the ports when sending/receiving.  As you said the Client sends a msg. to port 5000 and the Server is receiving this msg. on port 6000, right ? Where do i do wrong ?

Comment: Are you able to receive client message from server?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/434412/Android/Mobile/Android-Emulator-as-server-Socket

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience Roy! I really appreciate this.  I've reedited the Source Code above. It seems that Server receives msg. from Client (im sending system-time from client to the server just to send something that changes over time), but the Client does NOT receive anything from server. Can you take a look at the code above please ?

Comment: Im trying to do a simple 1 vs 1 player (or 2 vs 2)  networking game. It is like a tennis game :) and i hope that UDP packets will be sent fast enough for this simple kind of game over the internet between players wich join the server.  Im new to networking and android and i thank you very much for your support.

Comment: try a simple udp server-client connection from this link - http://www.coderanch.com/t/434412/Android/Mobile/Android-Emulator-as-server-Socket. Hope you will able to communicate. I suffered this type of problem as you and at last this link helped me. Yes i noticed your code.