# How to send http request to android emulator

Tags: android, http, request

i've created small http server in android , code is from this link just copy pasted in eclipse. 
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Samples/android-jp-kobe/net/cattaka/teamredwhite/HTTPServer.java.htm

How do i send simple request from browser to server now?  I would like something like this 127.0.0.1:12345?x=100&y=50 for example. Browsers always says that he didnt make connection with that url. 
In on create of main activity i just created a server with port 12345 and run .listen()

Comment: Have a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170660/android-udp-connection-not-receiving-any-data/10171114#10171114

Comment: Hey did you get solution to this problem ? I m working on something similar.

Comment: Hi, Could you able to find any solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 on is your local computer, not the emulator.

The emulator has its own [network address space](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses):

You're most likely looking for `10.0.2.15`, "the emulated device's own network/ethernet interface", e.g. `http://10.0.2.15:12345?x=100&y=50`.

Comment: browser says he didnt establish connection with that adress :(

Comment: Does the app run on the emulator or does it show exceptions in lgocat? Did you grant it the correct permissions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application?

Comment: I put internet permision. It is running on emulator it doesnt show exceptions in logcat :(